# q. i have made a program to find prime number in lisp but it is not working

Tags: lisp

```
(princ "ENTER ANY NUMBER : ")
(setq n (read))
(setq flag 0)

(loop for i from 2 to n-1
    (if (=(mod n i)0)
        (setq flag 1)))

(if (= flag 0)
    (format t "~d IS A PRIME NUMBER"n)
    (format t "~d IS NOT A PRIME NUMBER"n))
```

Comment: Why isn't it working? what errors are you getting? what output were you expecting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prime+numbers+%5Blisp%5D

Answer (score 0):

1. It would make your code much easier for other people to read if you
   would start each *top-level* form on a new line.
2. `n-1` is not lisp.  Try `(- n 1)`
3. You need a `do` in your loop.  That is:

   `(loop for i from 2 to (- n 1) do ...`

In other words:

```
(princ "ENTER ANY NUMBER : ")
(setq n (read))
(setq flag 0)
(loop for i from 2 to (- n 1) do
     (if (= (mod n i) 0)
         (setq flag 1)))
(if (= flag 0)
    (format t "~d IS A PRIME NUMBER"n)
  (format t "~d IS NOT A PRIME NUMBER"n))
```

Answer (score 0):

`n-1` is a symbol, and in your case it's an unbound symbol (that is, it does not have a value, as such). You probably mean one of `(- n 1)` or `(1- n)` (they both have the value of "one subtracted from n").

In general, you do not need to loop through all the numbers lower than `n`, only to `(isqrt n)` (the integer square root of the number, this is the positive square root if you're looking at a square number and is always at least as large as a factor for a non-prime number).

Instead of using flag variables and setting them, wrap your primality checker in a function and return early of you find a factor.

```
(defun primep (n)
  (loop for i from 2 upto (isqrt n)
    if (zerop (mod n i))
    do (return-from primep nil))
  'prime)
```